# pass information and display in label control in another screen in power apps

Tags: powerapps

How can I display the Login details(username, password) that user entered in login page in another screen in power apps?

I have designed login page in power apps which contain username and password. I have validated the details. Now I need to display the username and password that user entered in the login page in another screen in power apps.

Comment: A password should not be displayed to the user. The user is usually already logged in to their Microsoft account, is he not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for neophytes like me

**1) Terminology**

Screen1 = "Login screen"

Screen2 =  "Another screen"

On screen on there are two TextInput boxes:

username is labeled TextInput1

password is labeled TextInput2

**2) Create button (or icon) on Screen1**

**3) Edit the OnSelect of the button with a Navigate formula:**

Navigate(Screen2, ScreenTransition.Fade,({PassUsername:TextInput1.Text,PassPassword:TextInput2.Text})

**4) Create two labels on Screen2**

Set Default for one Label to PassUsername

Set Default for second Label PassPassword

Bathe in your success

Answer (score 0):

**Edit your OnSelect action button**:

Navigate(ViewSuppliers; Fade; { Username: TextInput1.Text; Password: TextInput2.Text})